# Will Firebase Dynamic Link work on app store unlisted app?

Tags: flutter, app-store, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have used Firebase Dynamic link for my flutter app. It works fine for android. I don't want to publish my app in public for the app store rather I want to publish the app as unlisted app. Will the dynamic link work for unlisted app.